# using one slicer (date) with two different tables and two different data columns in power bi. i want to solve this problem

Tags: powerbi, data-analysis, powerbi-desktop

using one slicer (date)  with two different tables and two different data columns in power bi. i want to solve this problem .I have already addressed this using a date table, but I am interested in exploring alternative solutions. The primary issue I encounter involves creating relationships, where one is active, and the other is inactive.

i want a possible solution of it to get rid of this problem as i'm tolerating this headache for quite long time .

Comment: You haven't presented a specific question, you haven't even described the problem. Edit your question above and rephrase it to a specific issue/question. Additionally, you might find this a useful read: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/guidance/relationships-active-inactive

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.